# How to prevent SSH setting LANG to an non-existent locale when logging in?

Tags: 12.04, ssh, locale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Locale variables have no effect in remote shell (perl: warning: Setting locale failed.)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144235/locale-variables-have-no-effect-in-remote-shell-perl-warning-setting-locale-f)

I have a minimal server install that only has English locales. That works great on its own, but when I log in from my Mac, `LANG` is set to `da_DK.UTF-8`. That causes a lot of error messages around the system, as the said locale does not exists.

Is there a way to prevent SSH from setting invalid values, or will preventing SSH from setting these altogether have a negative impact on my system?

Comment: While your verbage is different, it seems you are encountering the same problem as an earlier question.  The solution should also apply, although I haven't tested it.  If it does or does not work, please let us know in the comments here