# Can not correct locale settings

Tags: 12.04, configuration, locale

I am running an Ubuntu image provided by my company, it seemed to have some strange locale settings to begin with. Firefox uses the French dictionary by default and I get warnings when doing anything with SSH (git pull/push and normal SSH sessions).

Those warnings look like this:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_PAPER = "en_GB.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_GB.UTF-8",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_GB.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "en_GB.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_GB.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_GB.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_GB.UTF-8",
        LC_TIME = "en_GB.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_GB.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

I have been trying to set my locale to `en_GB.UTF-8` using information I have found on places such as askubuntu.com but I can't get it to work. My current `/etc/default/locale` file contains the following.

```
LANG="en_GB"
LANGUAGE="en_GB:en"
```

And here is the result of my `locale` command.

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Does anyone have any idea what can be set to correct this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think I might have fixed it by stopping my client sending my locale settings to the external server. Found in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/144448/4807). Need to try some things to make sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line:  `en_US.ISO-8859-1 ISO-8859-1` to this file: `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/en`.  Then run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` in the command line.