# Perl: problem with locales

Tags: proxy, perl, cgi

I'm trying to install CGIProxy on my Ubuntu server and according to the instructions I have to:

1. Copy the file `nph-proxy.cgi` onto your Web server somewhere, but not at the top Web directory, or else it will be easily discovered.
2. Change the file's permissions to be executable. On Unix and Mac, you can do this with the command

   ```
   chmod +x nph-proxy.cgi
   ```

   there are other ways.
3. In the directory where you copied `nph-proxy.cgi`, run the command

   ```
   ./nph-proxy.cgi install-modules
   ```

   (or in Windows, `perl nph-proxy.cgi install-modules`). This installs the optional Perl modules to e.g. let you visit secure sites. If you can't run this as root/administrator, it will still work, but see the instructions displayed at the end after all the scrolling text (which you can ignore). If it asks you any questions, you can just hit <kbd>Ret</kbd>.

I'm at step 3 but when I run the command

```
./nph-proxy.cgi install-modules
```

I get the following:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

I'm still pretty new to linux so I'm not sure what the issue is here, I've tried to run the command with sudo but still the same error.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about that, this is just a warning from Perl. You should be fine with the C locale.

Or, solve it by running

```
sudo apt-get install locales
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

It should generate the necessary locales.

Comment: But is the script still successfully installed or did it go through at all? Because I see a whole page of code instead of the normal GUI window when I access that script via a browser

Comment: I tried `locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=`  and it seems correct....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the locale variables are set by SSH.
If so here is the good answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/144448/136473

My choice is to comment out the `AcceptEnv LANG LC_*` line in the remote `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

Comment: Please do not post just a pointer to another question. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.